# Conditional element wise division in R

Tags: r

I have the following two matrices:

```
> dat <- cbind(c(1,1,2,3),c(55,23,65,67))
> dat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   55
[2,]    1   23
[3,]    2   65
[4,]    3   67
> cond <- cbind(c(1,2,3),c(0.9,1,1.1))
> cond
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1  0.9
[2,]    2  1.0
[3,]    3  1.1
```

Now, I would like to divide column 2 of `dat` with column 2 of `cond` conditional on the rows having the same value in column 1. That is:

```
55/0.9
23/0.9
65/1
67/1.1
```

How do I do that easily in R? I am also interested in solutions for `data.frames`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `match` assuming `cond` is unique in column 1:

```
dat[, 2] / cond[match(dat[, 1], cond[, 1]), 2]
# [1] 61.11111 25.55556 65.00000 60.90909
```

This will be faster than `merge`.  What match does is it finds the the index of the values in `cond` that match the value in `dat`, which you can then use to retrieve the values from `cond`.  This will also work with data frames.

To understand what `match` is doing, try looking at the result of:

```
match(dat[, 1], cond[, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

As @Anand Mahto suggested, merge the two matrices, then the calculation becomes simple:

```
df <- merge(dat, cond, by=1)
df[,2]/df[,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

FWIW,

```
Rgames> cond<-cbind(1:100,runif(100))
Rgames> dat<-cbind(sample(1:100,1e5,rep=TRUE),runif(1e5))
Rgames> library(microbenchmark)
Rgames> microbenchmark(brodie(dat,cond),shadow(dat,cond),times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
              expr        min         lq     median        uq
 brodie(dat, cond)   4.981001   5.411622   6.082569  21.57764
 shadow(dat, cond) 289.586938 304.098892 309.919966 353.00062
       max neval
  72.83944    10
 372.19423    10
```

Comment: +1, Thanks for the benchmarks.  Usually the improvement is on the order of ~10x, but I think the overhead kills `merge` on small merges like this one.